# How to print a graph correctly in C

Tags: c, graph, linked-list

So i have this file format like this

```
aAa     5     bBb
bBb     3     cCc
cCc     7     dDd
dDd     2     eEe
eEe     8     fFf
fFf     4     gGg
gGg     6     hHh
hHh     1     iIi
iIi     9     jJj
jJj     5     kKk
kKk     3     lLl
lLl     7     mMm
mMm     4     nNn
nNn     6     oOo
oOo     2     pPp
pPp     8     qQq
qQq     1     rRr
rRr     9     sSs
sSs     5     tTt
```

where `column one`represents `vertex1`, `column 2` represents `weight`, and `column 3` represents `vertex2` the vertex to which vertex 1 is connected to.

I have to do more but for now i just have to print this and we have to use linked lists to do it.

This is my take on the exercise

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct edge_s edge_t;
typedef struct vertex_s vertex_t;

struct edge_s {
    struct edge_s *next;
    int weight;
    vertex_t *vertex;
};

struct vertex_s {
    struct vertex_s *next;
    char *name;
    edge_t *edge;
    int traversed;
};

typedef struct graph_s {
    vertex_t *head;
    int n;
} graph_t;

vertex_t *find_vertex(graph_t *graph, const char name[20]);
void vertex_add(graph_t *graph, const char *name);
void edge_add(graph_t *graph, vertex_t *vertex1, vertex_t *vertex2, int weight);
graph_t *graph_init(void);
graph_t *fileread(const char *name);
void graph_write(graph_t *graph);

graph_t *graph_init() {
    graph_t *graph = malloc(sizeof(graph_t));
    if (graph == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    graph->head = NULL;
    graph->n = 0;

    return graph;
}

void edge_add(graph_t *graph, vertex_t *vertex1, vertex_t *vertex2, int weight) {
    edge_t *edge = malloc(sizeof(edge_t));
    if (edge == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    edge->weight = weight;
    edge->vertex = vertex2;
    edge->next = vertex1->edge;
    vertex1->edge = edge;
}

void vertex_add(graph_t *graph, const char *name) {
    vertex_t *vertex = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t));
    if (vertex == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    vertex->edge = NULL;
    vertex->traversed = 0;
    vertex->name = strdup(name);
    vertex->next = graph->head;
    graph->head = vertex;
}

vertex_t *find_vertex(graph_t *graph, const char name[20]) {
    vertex_t *v = graph->head;
    while (v != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(v->name, name) == 0)
            return v;
        v = v->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

graph_t *fileread(const char *name) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    graph_t *graph = graph_init();
    int weight;
    char name1[20], name2[20];
    vertex_t *vertex1, *vertex2;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %s", name1, &weight, name2) != EOF) {
        vertex1 = find_vertex(graph, name1);
        if (vertex1 == NULL) {
            vertex_add(graph, name1);
            vertex1 = graph->head; 
        }

        vertex2 = find_vertex(graph, name2);
        if (vertex2 == NULL) {
            vertex_add(graph, name2);
            vertex2 = graph->head; 
        }

        edge_add(graph, vertex1, vertex2, weight);
    }


    fclose(fp);
    return graph;
}

void graph_write(graph_t *graph) {
    vertex_t *vertex = graph->head;
    edge_t *edge;

    while (vertex != NULL) {
        printf("%s->", vertex->name);
        edge = vertex->edge;
        while (edge != NULL) {
            printf(" %d -> %s", edge->weight, edge->vertex->name);
            edge = edge->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        vertex = vertex->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    graph_t *graph = fileread("file");
    graph_write(graph);
    return 0;
}
```

The functions you can guess their meaning by the names so i doubt i need to explain much but if you question the not used variables in the structures its because its for the 2nd part of the exercise which i will solve after i print this.

Thing is when i print the exercise it shows this

```
tTt->
sSs-> 5 -> tTt
rRr-> 9 -> sSs
qQq-> 1 -> rRr
pPp-> 8 -> qQq
oOo-> 2 -> pPp
nNn-> 6 -> oOo
mMm-> 4 -> nNn
lLl-> 7 -> mMm
kKk-> 3 -> lLl
jJj-> 5 -> kKk
iIi-> 9 -> jJj
hHh-> 1 -> iIi
gGg-> 6 -> hHh
fFf-> 4 -> gGg
eEe-> 8 -> fFf
dDd-> 2 -> eEe
cCc-> 7 -> dDd
bBb-> 3 -> cCc
aAa-> 5 -> bBb
```

Which is mostly correct but the first row. The first row should not be there. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: wow.. AMAZING. Apparently tTt is simply not connected to anything. Its not a print error. The code is correct as it is

Comment: If you change the line `while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %s", name1, &weight, name2) != EOF) {` to `while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %s", name1, &weight, name2) == 3) {`, does the bug disappear?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Its not a bug. The code is correct. i asked chat gdp to come up with a txt file cuz i was too lazy to write it myself (i have picture slides so i cant copy paste) and didnt realize that the last node simply wasnt connected to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for `tTt`

[image]

in your input you will see that `tTt` has only ingoing vertex, hence your output looks good from the perspective of `tTt`. Of course, you might decide not to output items only having outgoing vertex, so in your

```
    while (vertex != NULL) {
        printf("%s->", vertex->name);
        edge = vertex->edge;
        while (edge != NULL) {
            printf(" %d -> %s", edge->weight, edge->vertex->name);
            edge = edge->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        vertex = vertex->next;
    }
```

instead of `printf`'ing your node, you can do the `printf` only when you realized there is something to point to. But this seems to be optional and your code seems to be good as it is.

Answer (score 1):

In `graph_write`, check to see if `edge` is `NULL` *before* printing the vertex name and `->`. If the vertex doesn't lead anywhere, there's no need to print anything.

```
void graph_write(graph_t *graph) {
    vertex_t *vertex = graph->head;
    edge_t *edge;

    while (vertex != NULL) {
        edge = vertex->edge;

        if (edge != NULL) {
            printf("%s->", vertex->name);

            while (edge != NULL) {
                printf(" %d -> %s", edge->weight, edge->vertex->name);
                edge = edge->next;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        vertex = vertex->next;
    }
}
```